# Windows form SQL Server connection string issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a Windows Forms application written in C# using SQL Server 2012 Express as its database.

I need a connection string to work on any PC.

I try to put the `.mdf` file in `DataDirectory` or drive `C:` or `C:\ProgramData`

```
DataSource=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\mydb.mdf;Pooling=False;
```

In this case the error is:

> Failed to update .mdf database because the database is read-only

If I try to use

```
user instance=True;
```

in the connection string, I get the following error :

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed.

If I try to put the `.mdf` file in user application data `AppRoaming` folder it's not supported and returns error :

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

So how to set my connection string and where should the `.mdf` file be stored?

Please help me

And thanks in advance

Comment: in this  case mdf file should be in

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.express\MSSQL\DATA

Comment: Maybe try a shorter path (like c:\test) and make sure nothing else has got the db open.

Comment: I try put the file is read only

Comment: there are no privilige to write database at that location.Can you install in another location and see?

Comment: yes I try C:\ProgramData

Comment: I try Integrated Security=false;Initial Catalog=

Comment: give an error Additional information: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

Comment: I think its should be Initial Catalog= but where I have put the MDF file ??

Comment: Possible duplicate [mdf is read only][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026925/unable-to-update-database-mdf-is-read-only

Comment: I read all of them and not solve my problem I also try to set

Comment: Initial Catalog=file path give me error login failed for user System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database requested by the login. The login failed.